# SQL insert new data to all customer

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-insert

Hi i have a problem that i need to insert new data to all customer. however there are many duplicated customer id in this table like

Table customer transcation record

| transcation ID | customer ID | detail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | detail |
| 2 | 1 | detail |
| 3 | 2 | detail |
| 4 | 3 | detail |
| 5 | 3 | detail |
| 6 | 3 | detail |

i want to insert new data to all existing customer and no repeat the customer ID(eg customer ID 1 customer only will be added 1 times)

INSERT INTO Table customer transcation record ( transcation ID, customer ID, detail)
VALUES ('', ''. '2024 red pocket');

what i want to do is: add "red pocket2024" to all customer

| transcation ID | customer ID | detail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | detail |
| 2 | 1 | detail |
| 3 | 2 | detail |
| 4 | 3 | detail |
| 5 | 3 | detail |
| 6 | 3 | detail |
| 7 | 1 | red pocket2024 |
| 8 | 2 | red pocket2024 |
| 9 | 3 | red pocket2024 |

Comment: If you do not need in these duplicates then delete them from the table firstly. And create according unique index which will prevent duplicates in future. *i want to insert new data to all customer and no repeat the customer ID* INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. After the clearing and indexing mentioned above.

Comment: I have a question , you want insert new data or you want update date ??? and customer_ID it is (nut Null)???

Comment: Not at all clear, please add expected outcome as text based on the sample data.

Comment: @Akina, i want to keep the duplicates customer ID, just all new data row to all customer 1 time. i am sorry my question is no clear, i alreay updated it, please have a look thank you

Comment: @P.Salmon i just want to add new data row to all customer 1 time. i am sorry my question is no clear, i alreay updated it, please have a look thank you

Comment: @AmerAlMunajjed i want to insert new data to all existing customer,  i am sorry my question is no clear, i alreay updated it, please have a look thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your transaction_ID is an autoincrement Value
You can do something like this

```
INSERT INTO TableA ( customer_ID,detail)
SELECT DISTINCT customer_ID, 'red pocket2024'
FROM TableA
```

If transction_ID is not an autoincrement, you a much more complex query

Comment: thanks for your reply, however thare are many customer ID are duplicated like transcation recorde: customer 1 buy apple, customer 1 buy bannna etc.. so i use this code for find customer out: SELECT * FROM `oc_customer_transaction` GROUP BY `customer_id` HAVING COUNT(*) = 1; is it possible to substitute customer ID?

Comment: what for the DISTINCT will exclude all duplicate  custsomer_ids, so you get only 1 row for every custmerid, no need to group by and of course every valid SELECT can be used as well as your GROUP BY, but there is as i said no need to group